# ¿Por qué no se abren los subitems de mi menú desplegable?

Tags: jquery, html, html5, css

Estoy haciendo un menú desplegable con jQuery y llevo lo siguiente:

```js
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('ul li:has(ul)').click(
      function (e) {
        $(this).find('ul').css({ display: "block" });
      },
      function (e) {
        $(this).find('ul').css({ display: "none" });
      }
    );
    $('#MainMenu > ul > li > a').click(function () {
      $('#MainMenu li').removeClass('active');
      $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
      var checkElement = $(this).next();
      if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
        $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
        checkElement.slideUp('normal');
      }
      if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
        $('#MainMenu ul ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
        checkElement.slideDown('normal');
      }
      if ($(this).closest('li').find('ul').children().length == 0) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
ul li ul {

  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="MainMenu" class="active">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></span>  Configuración</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span>  Catálogo</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>  Líneas</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>  Grupos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>  Tipos de proveedor</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>  Grupo de cliente</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>  Tipo de movimiento</a></li>
            <li class="last"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>  Sucursales</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span>  Parámetros</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span>  Utilerías</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>  Procesos de cálculos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>  Procesos de cierres</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>  Reintegraciones</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span>  Usuarios</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>  Configuración de usuarios</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>  Perfiles</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>  Seguridad</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></span>   Catálogos</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span>  Compras</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span>  Ventas</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span>  Clientes</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span>  Inventarios</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span>  Logística</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span>  Contabilidad</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span>  Informes</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span>  Empleados</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span>  Equipos</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-screenshot"></span>  Logística</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span>  Modulo de logística</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span>  Envios y entregas</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Todo funciona perfectamente excepto los subitem dentro de "Configuración > Catálogo" los cuales no se despliegan y sigo sin tener idea del por qué.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que sólo se comprueba el primer nivel del menú cuando se hace click (`#MainMenu > ul > li > a`), por lo que no se tiene en cuenta los siguientes niveles. Por ejemplo, ese selector hace que se abra "Configuración", pero no aplica para "Catálogo" (porque para ese haría falta algo como `#MainMenu > ul > li > ul > li > a`).

Una posible solución sería hacer más genérico el selector para que seleccione cualquier enlace dentro de `#MainMenu` y no sólo el primer nivel, para ello quita los `>` y déjalo en `#MainMenu ul li a`.

Aparte de eso, podrías simplificar el código considerablemente (y seguramente se puede simplificar aún más), aunque no sé si ese código adicional lo necesitas para otras cosas o no. Una versión reducida con el selector más genérico y quitando el código innecesario:

```js
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#MainMenu ul li a').click(function () {
      $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
      var checkElement = $(this).next();
      if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
        $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
        checkElement.slideUp('normal');
      } else if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
        checkElement.slideDown('normal');
      }
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
ul li ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="MainMenu" class="active">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></span>  Configuración</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span>  Catálogo</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>  Líneas</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>  Grupos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>  Tipos de proveedor</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>  Grupo de cliente</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>  Tipo de movimiento</a></li>
            <li class="last"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>  Sucursales</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span>  Parámetros</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span>  Utilerías</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>  Procesos de cálculos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>  Procesos de cierres</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>  Reintegraciones</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span>  Usuarios</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>  Configuración de usuarios</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>  Perfiles</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>  Seguridad</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></span>   Catálogos</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span>  Compras</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span>  Ventas</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span>  Clientes</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span>  Inventarios</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span>  Logística</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span>  Contabilidad</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span>  Informes</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span>  Empleados</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span>  Equipos</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-screenshot"></span>  Logística</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span>  Modulo de logística</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span>  Envios y entregas</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```